# what if parent is terminated with exit()

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Program::

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>  //standard input output header file
#include <unistd.h>  // POSIX operating system API
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    system("clear");
    if(pid < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed to create process\n");
      return 1;
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
      printf("This is the child process \'%d\' of \'%d\'\n\n",getpid(),getppid());
      execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    }
   else
   {
      printf("This is parent process \'%d\' my parent is %d\n\n",getpid(),getppid());
      wait(NULL);
      printf("DONE\n\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is the child process '3979' of '3978'
This is parent process '3978' my parent is '3681'

DONE

vijay@workspace:~/Documents/os$ a.out  os_fork.c
```

I am unable to understand why the execlp() got executed after parent process not along with child process

Comment: Some quirk of output buffering in your terminal/shell, probably.  Your code looks fine.

Comment: I'm confused as to what's unexpected about your output. Could you clarify what you expected to see and why you're surprised?

Comment: I think I see what he's asking: why does the output from `ls` appear after `DONE`, even though the parent is calling `wait()` before printing it.

Comment: @CarlNorum I've never heard of terminals doing output buffering. And the shell isn't even in the I/O path. Output buffering is normally only done by the stdio library, but the buffer is flushed when the process exits.

Comment: Well, that's what makes OP's output weird, right?

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Hi every one, what i expect is :

Comment: after execution of " printf("This is the child process \'%d\' of \'%d\'\n\n",getpid(),getppid());" in child process even "execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);" should be executed but "execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);" is executed after the parent printf() is executed and that output of "execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);" is also after "vijay@workspace:~/Documents/os$" why is that so?